# How to access a value from a drop down box selection to use in url_for

Tags: python, flask

I have the below working for the top summary link - drop box and a submit changes the type. But I want to create links for each circle that also uses the value from the drop down box.  I tried the below under active users..

`<a href="{{ url_for('details', active='active', type=type) }}`

But when I click the link it has no type information. Is this possible?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form name="types" action ='{{ url_for('summary') }}' method="GET" >
        <select name="type">
        {% for type in types %}
            <option value="{{ type }}">{{ type }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-primary-primary">Select Type</button></td>
    </form>
    <div class="circles">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="circle-title">Total Users</div>
                <a href="{{ url_for('details') }}"><div class="circle">{{ total_users }}</div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="circle-title">Active Users</div>
                <a href="{{ url_for('details', active='active', type=type) }}"><div class="circle">{{ total_active }}</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="circle-title">Total Logged</div>
                <div class="circle">{{ '{:,}'.format(total) }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="circle-title">Attendence</div>
                <div class="circle">{{ '{:.0%}'.format(attendance) }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jinja runs ar the server. At that time there is no checkbox selecione. You can use javascript to do this on client side.

Comment: Typing on phone Just sucks, sorry

Comment: hah no worries.  So you're saying that I should not be using Flask to create the drop down box?  That it should be Javascript?

Comment: Not really. As far as I understood you want to use the selected value from the _select_ to create a link, but value is selected after jinja has compiled the template, so at that time the selection didn't happen yet

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{% for type in types %}
  <a href="{{ url_for('details', active='active', type=type) }}"><div class="circle">{{ total_active }}</div></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But I want what was selected from the drop down box?